# Date cleaning in excel,date values align to the left

Tags: r, excel

I have excel file a date column, some of date are align to the right while others to the left.when i read the into r am getting this error.

> Expecting date in A3547 / R3547C1: got '13/04/2018'

on dates align to the left. I have tried to clean the date in excel with no success,

Comment: Left tends to be text, right tends to be numbers - have you checked the formatting?

Comment: Actually i have recognized the problem, in this particular date column the format is dd/mm/yyyy but my excel setting is mm/dd/yyyy as there are other date columns in the workbook do not have the problem.How do i go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar to this

- I have extracted the day, month and year from the string date using
  some formulas
- After that I have recreated the actual date from the
  extracted day, month and year values

[image]

Formulas are as below

[image]

```
B2: =FIND("/",A2)
C2: =FIND("/",A2,1+FIND("/",A2))
D2: =LEFT(A2,B2-1)
E2: =MID(A2,B2+1,C2-B2-1)
F2: =RIGHT(A2,4)
G2: =DATE(F2,E2,D2)
```

Depending upon your actual data you may need to amend the formulas a little bit.

Comment: If it solved your problem kindly do an upvote as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether all the cells in the column has date format and same date format.

Sometimes dates can be enter as text strings or other custom formats. Then there is a possibility to getting error like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the data looks like in excel, both date and text

[image: Excel Table]

Load the same in MS Excel Power Query Editor, select the date column, Under the Transform Tab select "Split Column, By Delimiter", select "/" as the delimiter and Click OK. This separated the date into Month, Day and Year+Time.
Highlight the Day Column first, then Month, then Year+Time ...in that order, and then click "Merge Columns" under the Transform Tab.
Highlight the now Merged column and under "Data Type", select "Date/Time". You can now go back to the Home tab and Select Close & Load to get the cleaned data into Excel... as below;

[image: Cleaned Date]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of tables. Instead use the table function in stackoverflow.